# Node Mongo Db Finding Records of few minutes

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am facing an issue, actually I have mongoose module

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var saveVisitorsDetails = new Schema({
  userId : { type: String, unique: true, dropDups: true},
  visitorName : { type: String},
  visitorMobileNumber : { type: Number},
  expireStatus : { type : Number},
  clientUnreadMessageCount : { type : Number},
  adminUnreadMessageCount : { type : Number},
  visibleVisitorChat : { type : Boolean},
  visibleAdminChat : { type : Boolean},
  displayAdminChat : { type : Boolean},
  activeChat : { type : Boolean},
  adminId : { type : String},
  visitorMsg : { type : String},
  msgTiming : { type : Date},
  showVisitorCross : { type : Boolean},
  showVisitorMinimize : { type : Boolean},
  newMessageForAdmin : { type : Boolean},
  expireUserForAdmin : { type : Boolean},
  visitorLocationObject : { type : Object }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Visitor',saveVisitorsDetails);
```

I want to query all documents of msgTiming 5 minutes from now, but I can't get it.

My query is

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Visitor = require('./models/visitor');
app.post('/loadVisitorDetails', function(req, res){
    Visitor.collection.find({adminId : req.body.adminId ,expireStatus : 0}).sort({msgTiming : -1}).toArray(function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            var obj = {
                rslt : result,
                id : req.body.adminId
            }
            res.send(obj);
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know how to find all records of 5 minutes from now and response array should be on msgTiming arrangement

Please help me, I have been facing this problem for the past 2 days; any suggestions will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice answer by Manjeet, just a small correction it should be after.getMinutes - 5 instead of +.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Visitor = require('./models/visitor');
app.post('/loadVisitorDetails', function (req, res) {
    let now = new Date();
    let after = new Date();
    after.setMinutes(after.getMinutes() - 5);
    let critria = {
        $and: [{
            adminId: req.body.adminId
        }, {
            expireStatus: 0
        }, {
            msgTiming: {
                $gte: now,
                $lte: after
            }
        }]
    };

    let projection = {}
    let options = { sort:{ msgTiming : -1 }}

    Visitor.collection.find(critria,projection,options,function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result)
        }
    })       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can do like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Visitor = require('./models/visitor');
app.post('/loadVisitorDetails', function (req, res) {

    let now = new Date();
    let after = new Date();
    after.setMinutes(after.getMinutes() + 5);
    let critria = {
        $and: [{
            adminId: req.body.adminId
        }, {
            expireStatus: 0
        }, {
            msgTiming: {
                $gte: now,
                $lte: after
            }
        }]
    };

    let projection = {}
    let options = { sort:{ msgTiming : -1 }}

    Visitor.collection.find(critria,projection,options,function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result)
        }
    })       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [moment npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)

first change your  `msgTiming : { type : Date},` to  `msgTiming : { type : Number}` in Visitor Model Schema .

when you inserting a recored, set `msgTiming: moment().unix()` in your Object.

it will store `current unix timestamp in seconds` like 1318874398

```
app.post('/loadVisitorDetails', function(req, res){
       var currenttime= moment().unix();
       var 5minbefore=currenttime-300;  // (5 * 60)
       Visitor.collection.find({adminId : req.body.adminId,expireStatus : 0,msgTiming:{$gt: 5minbefore, $lte : currenttime}},
                     function(err, result){
                         console.log(result);
                      });
});
```